# Blazor Upside down List for virtualize component

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Im developing a chat app
Im using virtualize method and its been a couple days that im trying to figure out how to make this list render from bottom to the top
as long as I didnt find anything on the web I decided to ask it here

here is my code :

```
  <Virtualize Context="message" ItemsProvider="@ItemsProvider" @key="user.FrontId"  >

                                    @{
                            
                                         string classes = "";
                                         if (message.ToUserId == User.UserId)
                                         {
                                             classes = classes + " user";
                                         }
                                     }
                                    

                                     <div id="@message.Id" class="single-msg @classes">
                                         @if (classes == "")
                                         {
                                             <div class="triangle-topleft single-msg-shap">
                                             </div>
                                         }

                                         <div class="single-msg-content">
                                             <div class="msg-detail" style="padding: 20px; padding-top: 0px;">
                                                 <span> @message.Message </span>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="msg-action">
                                                 <span> @message.ShortCreateAt </span>
                                             </div>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>



                                 </Virtualize>
```

and here is how its rendering :
[image: rendering list regularly]

I cant find any solutions for this problems ,  and also dont want to use javascript . because its not proper to use javascript while you are using blazor .
not logical

Comment: CSS flexboxes allow you to change the order of display of elements.  Maybe try that.  Display issues in Blazor are very rarely about Blazor, and are almost always really CSS questions.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I did what you said , its working , this fixed the direction . thank you but
unfortunately virtualize component still renders from the end of the list  (for example from record 100 to 0)

Comment: The order that `Virtualize` renders is based on the order of the `IEnumerable` provided by `@ItemsProvider` in the `ItemsProviderResult`.  You don't show that code.  Change the ordering in that and you will change the ordering in `Virtualize`.

Comment: I wouldn't use virtualization by default.  Most text exchanges are a few dozen lines at most-- a trivial amount of data to just download in one go.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for @Bennyboy1973 for your help,
and i fixed this issue by copy and modify the virtualize component locally in my project
now its working properly

Modify the Virtualize Clone Class Like this:

```
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollToBottom");
    }
```

and add inside script like this:

```
function scrollToBottom() {
var objDiv = document.getElementById("user-chat-content");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}
```

Final Result when it loads (Recent chats):

[image]